# how to fix: 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem when I try get response from my function, I'm just start use Promises, so maybe I did something wrong.
When I start my app, I get error then: `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.
What I did wrong?
Until I start using Promises, everything worked well, after I tried to change app logic it crashed.
My main file below:

```
/app.js

const request = require('request');
const yargs = require('yargs');

const geocode = require('./geocode/geocode')

const argv = yargs
    .options({
        a: {
            demand: true,
            alias: 'address',
            string: true,
            describe: 'Address to fetch weather for'
        }
    })
    .help()
    .alias('help', 'h')
    .argv;

geocode.geocodeAddress(argv.a)
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
},
(error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

my geocode file:

```
/geocode/geocode.js
const request = require('request');

const geocodeAddress = (address) => {
    const encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(address);

    request({
        url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=myKey&address=${encodedAddress}`,
        json: true
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if(err){
                reject('Unable to connect to Google servers.')
            } else if (body.status === 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                reject('Unable find any address.')
            } else if (body.status === 'OK') {
                const lat = body.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                const lon = body.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                const adrs = body.results[0].formatted_address;
                const answer = {
                    lat: lat,
                    lon: lon,
                    address: adrs
                };
                resolve(answer);
            }
        })
    })
};

module.exports.geocodeAddress = geocodeAddress;
```

Comment: `return request({`

Comment: `return`ing is indeed necessary, but the explicit `Promise` constructor should wrap the whole invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that solve it for me:

```
const request = require('request');

const geocodeAddress = (address) => {
    const encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(address);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        request({
        url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=myKey&address=${encodedAddress}`,
        json: true
    }, (err, res, body) => {
            if(err){
                reject('Unable to connect to Google servers.')
            } else if (body.status === 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                reject('Unable find any address.')
            } else if (body.status === 'OK') {
                const lat = body.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                const lon = body.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                const adrs = body.results[0].formatted_address;
                const answer = {
                    lat: lat,
                    lon: lon,
                    address: adrs
                };
                resolve(answer);
            }
        })
    })
};

module.exports.geocodeAddress = geocodeAddress;
```

Answer (score 1):

it is probably because your geocodeAddress is a constant and not an async function.

blind shot try:

```
async geocodeAddress (address) {
```

and like @liam said, try:

```
return request({...})
```

Comment: There no need to use `async` here. Handling the promise is fine as it is. The only thing that's missing is the return statement